# FBUserSettingsViewController hide navigation bar

Tags: facebook, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

When I present FBUserSettingsViewController modally, it has a navigation bar with cancel and done bar buttons on it.

How to hide it?

```
FBUserSettingsViewController *settings = PF_FBUserSettingsViewController.new;
settings.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:settings animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: No. As I understand, development of this controller is just started.

Comment: P.S. And I decided to use iOS6 natural FB login.

Comment: @Chris see the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the toolbar by setting both the **doneButton** and **cancelButton** of the **FBUserSettingsViewController** to **nil**:

```
self.settingsViewController.doneButton = nil;
self.settingsViewController.cancelButton = nil;
```

This has been verified in Facebook SDK 3.2.